# Using files saved on external storage in android application

Tags: android, storage, external, soundpool

In my android app, the user can create wav files. I save them in a folder in the external storage. Once created, I want to play them via SoundPool. But for this, I need an ID such as R.raw.sound1 ...

Is there a way to do this in android ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the resource ID. SoundPool has two other `load()` methods. See this one: [load(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Ok, it works. I give the possibility to record 3 different sounds. They can choose which one to play with radiobuttons, then click play. The three sounds are recorded fine, but whatever I click on, only the last one is played. And it crashes when I play it twice (I repeat the sample indefinitly with a do{ }while(play). I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are required for the bundled resources of an Android application. If you want to play an external file with `SoundPool`, you should use one of the following methods:

```
public int load (String path, int priority);

public int load (FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length, int priority);
```